# How do you create a custom filter formula based on another column's values?

Tags: google-sheets

I've got **Table A** like so:

```
Names     Age 
-----------------
John      3
Jane      4
Mary      5 
John      6
Chris     7
Mary      8
Michael   9
```

and **Table B** like so

```
Cool Names
--------
Mary
Michael
```

I want to create a filter on **Table A** such that it only shows me names that appear in **Table B**.  Which means I should have a resulting view that looks like:

```
Names     Age 
-----------------
Mary      5 
Mary      8
Michael   9
```

The formula needs to go [image]

into that box.  Here's a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/147H_BS0S-Pt6IdLsNQOk5pdsCUtRNLSk2C-Uk6Om7_k/edit?usp=sharing).  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll accept anything that creates my filter.  I've tried putting in `=FILTER(A2:A, COUNTIF('Cool Names'!A:A, A2:A)>0)` into the field, but it doesn't work.  That forumla works if I put it into a normal cell, so it feels like that field is looking for something more specific.  Not sure what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Names are in ColumnA and Table B is in ColumnG then a custom formula of:

```
=countif(G:G,A2)
```

should work.

My preference however would be for the [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) function:

```
=FILTER(A2:A,COUNTIF(TableB,A2:A))
```

where `TableB` is a named range (in the same document, but not necessarily the same sheet).

(And I'd not bother to cater for headers, `=FILTER(A:A,COUNTIF(TableB,A:A))` should be adequate.)

Comment: This works, but what if Table B is in another sheet?